# Text box validation prototype library +PHP

Tags: ajax, json

I have this form in the file abc.php and I want to validate the text boxes with id's 'Event Name' and 'Code Name'. User has to fill both of these and 'Event Name' should start with EV_ and 'Code Name' should start with CD_. I'm a newbie (fresh off plane :P) to AJAX and JSON

```
<form class="abc" name="abc" id="form" action="validate.php" method="post">
<label for="event_name"> Event Name: </label>
<input type="text" class="required" name="event_name" id="Event Name"/><br/><br/>
<label for="code_name">   Code Name:  </label>
<input type="text" class="required"  name="code_name" id="Code Name"/><br/><br/>
</form>
```

I'm using prototype library.
Basically, AJAX request has to be triggered on submit, and JSON should be returned to the client asking the user to enter the event name and code name as specified.

I would really appreciate any help regarding this. I have been surfing for like 12 hours but could not get simple code anywhere. Plz help me guys!

Thanks